# ASP.NET issues with Navigation, Razor Views, Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller, navigation, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on a simple website application for school and I'm having issues with navigation.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for this project.

I'm trying to navigate away from the `Views/Home/Index` to `Views/Product/List`, but have been unable (404 error).

Here is `_Layout`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">SportsPro</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="List">Products</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Technician" asp-action="List">Technicians</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="List">Customers</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Incident" asp-action="List">Incidents</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Registration" asp-action="GetCustomer">Registrations</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </nav>
```

View `Views/Product/List`:

```
@model Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Products";
}
<h1>Product Manager</h1>
<form>...
```

`HomeController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SportsPro.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SportsPro.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private SportsProContext context { get; set; }

        public HomeController(SportsProContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }
       ....
    }
}
```

`ProductController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SportsPro.Models;

namespace SportsPro.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private SportsProContext context { get; set; }

        public ProductController(SportsProContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Add()
        {
            ViewBag.Action = "Add";
            ViewBag.ProductCode = context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
            return View("Edit", new Product());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Action = "Edit";
            ViewBag.ProductCode = context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
            var product = context.Products.Find(id);
            return View(product);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (product.ProductID == 0)
                    context.Products.Add(product);
                else
                    context.Products.Update(product);

                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("List", "Product");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Action = (product.ProductID == 0) ? "Add" : "Edit";
                ViewBag.ProductCode = context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
                return View(product);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var product = context.Products.Find(id);
            return View(product);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Delete(Product product)
        {
            context.Products.Remove(product);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("List", "Product");
        }
    }
}
```

Are any other examples of code that might help resolve my problem? I feel like my issues lies within my `ProductController`.

Comment: And how are you trying to navigate? Where is your LIst action?

Comment: That's where I'm stuck - trying to figure out how to implement List in ProductController, but I've been unsuccessful with a number of attempts at functions to do so. I feel like I'm trudging through the mud during the phase of my learning experience. All the calling back and forth and sideways and upside-down mixes me up sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to click on Products button on your menu bar and go to the page that you list your products.

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link active" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="List">Products</a>
```

Meaning of the above code is as follows: Go to your **Product controller** and to **List action** of that controller.

To be able to do that you first have to create a function called List() in your Product controller. So far you don't seem to have a function called List() in your Product controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List()
{
     var products = await context.Products.ToListAsync();
     return View(products);
}
```

After creating the List function you should return the model from your controller to your Views/Product/List.cshtml

Then your can use that model inside your view as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

<div>
    @foreach(var product in Model){
        <a>@product.Name</a>
    }
<div>
```

Comment: Ok sweet, the function in ProductController makes sense (I knew I needed 'List', but couldn't figure out how/where), although I'm not familiar with using 'async', 'Task', or 'await'.

I am also a little confused on how/where to use the '@foreach' code. I tried using is in the List view, but I'm getting an error (CS1579 - foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Product' because 'Product' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'), which I have not figured out how to resolve on my own just yet.

Comment: Hi @Alex,  @foreach code should in your Views/Product/List.cshtml and the error message means you need change `@Model Product` to `@Model List<Product>`.

Comment: You can remove 'async', 'Task', and 'await' for now. They are thread related structures. You don't need them for now. 'foreach' is used to iterate through items in a collection. Since your view contains Product (which is an object), the foreach loop cannot iterate. You should send a list of products to your List view and initialize your model inside the view as '@model IEnumerable<Product>' instead of '@model' Product.

Comment: @EmreUtkuSolak Thank you for that clarification, this had been a bit of a learning curve for me. I changed the model in my view and added the foreach code, but am now receiving error CS1061 ('IEnumerable<Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Name'...missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)). My controllers and models appear to have all the necessary using directives so I'm trying to figure that out now.

Comment: .Name is just a sample attribute in your entity. I gave that as an example. You can replace that with an attribute of your Product model. I you put "." after "product" it will show you the possible attributes contained by your Product model. It can be <a>@product.Name</a> or <a>@product.Count</a> or <a>@product.Id</a> ...It completely depends on your model's attributes and what you want to show about your product in your view.